# Plotting 3 continuous variables and one boolean variable

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I ran some simulations exploring a 3D space of parameters and recorded by TRUE or FALSE the presence and absence of a given pattern. Here is some data to make a reproducible example

```
v1 = 1:12
v2 = c(0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000)
v3 = c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 2, 10, 20, 100)
data = expand.grid(v1, v2, v3)
names(data) = c("v1", "v2", "v3")
VResponse = c()
for (row in 1:nrow(data)) {if (data$v1[row] > 8 | data$v1[row] < 2) {if (data$v2[row] > 0.1){if (data$v3[row] > 0.1){VResponse[row] = T} else {VResponse[row] = F}} else {VResponse[row] = F}} else {if (data$v2[row] > 10 & data$v3[row] > 0.1){VResponse[row] = T} else {VResponse[row] = F}}}
data = cbind(data, VResponse)
```

My goal is to make a plot that displays the zones where `VResponse` is TRUE and the zones where `VResponse` is FALSE. I made 2D plots with `plot` and `ggplot` by taking into account 2 of the three variables and plotting `VResponse` in two different colors (actually plotting the zones using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753331/replacing-points-of-color-by-a-uniform-colored-surface)). I tried to make a plot in three dimension using `plot3d` from the `rgl` package but I didn't find it very handy.

In addition to be able to have zones of different colours, I would need the axes `v2` and `v3` to be displayed on a logarithmic scale. Can you help me using this fake data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure what your problem might be (after fixing the mathematical nonsense.)

```
require(rgl)
 data$lv3<- log(data$v3)
 data$lv2<- log(data$v2)
 with(data, plot3d( v1,lv2,lv3, col=c("red","blue")[1+VResponse]))
 #after some rotation with the cursor:
 rgl.snapshot("out.png")
```

[image]

Comment: I agree that my question was unclear sorry about that. Thanks for your answer.